# How do i test a function which uses filepath.walk

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a function which gets all PDF files in a directory and returns the files if there are some.

```
func GetPdfFiles(path string) ([]string, error) {
var files []string
err := filepath.Walk(path, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".pdf") {
        files = append(files, path)
    }
    return nil
})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
if files == nil {
    return nil, errors.New("No PdfFiles found.")
}
return files, nil
}
```

My Test function gets the error: nil, from the filepath.Walk function which requires a anonymous function that returns an error, but it should get the error from the if statements like in the case of the second testcase with no files it should return errors.New("No PdfFiles found.").
How can i test it correctly.

```
func TestGetPdfFiles(t *testing.T) {
type args struct {
    path string
}

cwd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

tests := []struct {
    name    string
    args    args
    want    []string
    wantErr bool
}{
    {name: "2PdfFiles", args: args{path: fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/", cwd)}, want: []string{fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/test-1.pdf", cwd), fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/test-2.pdf", cwd)}, wantErr: false},
    {name: "noPdfFiles", args: args{path: fmt.Sprintf("%s", cwd)}, want: nil, wantErr: true},
}
for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
        got, err := GetPdfFiles(tt.args.path)
        if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
            t.Errorf("GetPdfFiles() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
            return
        }
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
            t.Errorf("GetPdfFiles() got = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Have some files and directories under ./testdata, commit them and use them for testing. Dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and modify your function to accept an implementation of `fs.FS`. That lets your tests pass it a mock file system.

- https://bitfieldconsulting.com/golang/filesystems
- https://www.gopherguides.com/articles/golang-1.16-io-fs-improve-test-performance

Or, perhaps simpler for your use case, modify your `GetPdfFiles()` to accept a directory walker function with the same signature as `path.WalkDir()`:

```
package main

import (
  "io/fs"
  "path"
  "path/filepath"
  "strings"
)

func GetPdfFiles(root string) ([]string, error) {
  return GetPdfFilesWithWalker(root, filepath.WalkDir)
}

type DirectoryWalker = func(string, fs.WalkDirFunc) error

func GetPdfFilesWithWalker(root string, walk DirectoryWalker) (fns []string, err error) {
  
  collectPdfFiles := func(fn string, info fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
    if ext := strings.ToLower(path.Ext(fn)); ext == ".pdf" {
      fns = append(fns, fn)
    }
    return nil
  }
  
  err = walk(root, collectPdfFiles)
  
  return fns, err
}
```

Now your `GetPdfFiles()` is a do-nothing wrapper that injects the default implementation (from `path/filepath`), and the core is in `GetPdfFilesWithWalker()`, against which you write your tests, passing in a suitable mock.

you can even construct a mock that will return errors, so you can test your error handling.

Your mock directory walker can be as simple as something like this (especially since you only use the `path` passed to the callback:

```
func MockDirectoryWalker(root string, visit fs.WalkDirFunc) (err error) {
  paths := [][]string{
    {root, "a"},
    {root, "a", "a.pdf"},
    {root, "a", "b.txt"},
    {root,"a", "b"},
    {root, "a", "b", "c.pdf"},
    {root, "a", "b", "d.txt"},
  }
  for _, p := range paths {
    fqn := path.Join(p...)
    var di fs.DirEntry
    visit(fqn, di, nil)
  }

  return err
}
```

Comment: I love you man.
I just had to implement my own `fs.DirEntry` struct to make it work for me (I rely on it in my WalkDirFunc to filter based on the name)
```
type mockFileInfo struct {
 fs.FileInfo
 name string
}

func (m mockFileInfo) Name() string {
 return m.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [T.TempDir()](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.TempDir) for a unique empty directory every time. This will guarantee repeatable results. The testing package will also take care of cleaning that:

```
func TestGetPdfFiles(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        path string
    }

    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    []string
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {name: "noPdfFiles", args: args{path: t.TempDir()}, want: nil, wantErr: true},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := GetPdfFiles(tt.args.path)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("GetPdfFiles() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("GetPdfFiles() got = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there isn't really a good way to do it.
so i removed the error checks and just return an empty array, it would've been too messy.
Also thanks to @Qasim Sarfraz for the T.TempDir idea.

```
func GetPdfFiles(path string) []string {
    var files []string
    filepath.Walk(path, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".pdf") {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files
}

func TestGetPdfFiles(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        path string
    }

    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    []string
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {name: "2PdfFiles", args: args{path: fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/", cwd)}, want: []string{fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/test-1.pdf", cwd), fmt.Sprintf("%s/testData/test-2.pdf", cwd)}},
        {name: "noPdfFiles", args: args{path: t.TempDir()}, want: nil},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got := GetPdfFiles(tt.args.path)
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("GetPdfFiles() got = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```